# webpack 3.8.1 facebook react import node module css not working

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using Facebook react with Webpack and I import node module CSS in my component. It's not working.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve("dist"),
    filename: "index_bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        query: {
          presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
          plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css?$/,
        loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
          "style-loader!css-loader?modules=true&localIdentName=[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
        )
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [new ExtractTextPlugin("./public/styles.css")]
};
```

**React component file**

> I import react-times css file

```
import React from "react";
import TimePicker from "react-times"; 
import "react-times/css/material/default.css";    

export default class Book extends React.Component {

  render() {

    return (
        <TimePicker />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain what means "is not working".  You get an error traceback or what?

Comment: No error log. only css not load.

Comment: when i using unpkg in html file css work fine

Comment: @LucaFabbri i send you screenshot. http://res.cloudinary.com/dp67gawk6/image/upload/c_scale,w_833/v1537004989/ballyhoo/EMAIL/stackoverflow.png

Comment: where is your index.js and if can share this over git it would be great

Comment: @SakhiMansoor     `    
`import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

import Root from "./root";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import reducer from "./reducers";

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(reducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(<Root store={store} />, document.getElementById("root"));
registerServiceWorker();
`

Comment: @SakhiMansoor this is my github link **https://github.com/sushantlp/ballyhoo**

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
// module
{
    test : /\.css$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: "style-loader",
    use: ['css-loader']
    })
}
// plugins
new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css")
```

Comment: i send you screenshot . http://res.cloudinary.com/dp67gawk6/image/upload/c_scale,w_833/v1537004989/ballyhoo/EMAIL/stackoverflow.png